# Distinct and Min

Tags: sql

I'm writing a query that has MIN and DISTINCT in my SELECT in BigQuery.

Example:

```
SELECT
  MIN(a),
  DISTINCT(b),
  c,
  d
```

BQ is telling me it expected the input to end but instead found DISTINCT. Anyone know why I can't use the DISTINCT function after MIN?

Comment: Please add some sample data, if possible.  Also, if the query you posted above is not the full query, please include the entire query.

Answer (score 0):

can u try this, i think DISTINCT is first and then func MIN

SELECT
DISTINCT(b),
MIN(a),
c,
d

Answer (score -1):

if u run sql DISTINCT function after MIN, MIN will be filter 1 data and then DISTINCT not working, u must be run DISTINCT at first and then from the DISTINCT will be search with function MIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT(b), MIN(a), c, d from NameOfTable
```